# fileupload.PostedFile.SaveAs not save image in folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, save-as

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fup.PostedFile.FileName);
fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;

if (Path.GetExtension(fup.PostedFile.FileName) == ".jpg" || Path.GetExtension(fup.PostedFile.FileName) == ".jpeg" || Path.GetExtension(fup.PostedFile.FileName) == ".bmp" || Path.GetExtension(fup.PostedFile.FileName) == ".png")
{
    string s = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName);
    fup.PostedFile.SaveAs(s);
    how = "file";

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update product set sub_cat = '" + ddlcategory.SelectedValue.Trim() + "',name='" + Pnam.Text.Trim() + "',pic='" + fileName + "',price=" + price.Text.Trim() + ",description='" + desc.Text.Trim() + "',unit='" + ddlUnit.SelectedValue.Trim() + "',catgeory='" + ddlcat.SelectedValue.Trim() + "'  where product_id=" + pid.Text.Trim(), cn);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    gvproduct.EditIndex = -1;
    fillgrid();

    show = "Update";
}
```

This is my code to save image file in Images(folder). After execution this query  no image is save in folder. But these images show in `GridView`,
which code is like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ID="imgPd" runat="server" Height="60px"
          ImageUrl='<%#"~/Images/"+Eval("pic").ToString() %>' Width="60px" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadGV" runat="server" Width="50px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made below a method to save file into folder.

You can pass *folder name* (e.g. `Images`) and *file name* (e.g. `FileUploadGV.PostedFile`) to the method.

```
private void UploadFile(string FolderName, HttpPostedFile file)
{
    // make folder path
    string FolderPath = "~\\" + FolderName;

    // create folder directory info
    DirectoryInfo FolderDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(FolderPath));

    // check if folder directory not exist
    if (!FolderDir.Exists)
    {
        // create directory
        FolderDir.Create();
    }

    // define file path
    string FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(FolderPath), file.FileName);

    // check if file not exist
    if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        // save file into folder directory
        file.SaveAs(FilePath);
    }
}
```

**Extra:** For deleting file from folder use this method:

```
private void DeleteFile(string FileName)
{
    // make file path
    string path = Server.MapPath(FileName);

    // check if file exist
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        // delete file from folder
        File.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Image stores in folder but these are not included in project.How can I include these image in project.

Comment: Go to Solution Explorer --> Click on Show All Files icon then Right click on file --> Select Include In Project from the popup.

Comment: There is problem when I upload this project on server.Image is not save in folder

Comment: application pool folder accessing problem

Comment: If you've new problem then ask a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

On server,Images(in which I was saving image) folder has no application pool permission.After giving read and write permission.This problem has been resolved.